# Unindent code block in IPython under cmd.exe?

Tags: ipython

I run IPython in cmd.exe as interactive shell. When typing code in this interactive shell, it does autoindent (`%autoindent` magic is on) or I could use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to indent manually, but it doesn't do unindent automatically even after line with `return` or `raise` statement, either the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>. Is there a quick way to do undent manually instead of press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> for a few times?

An example is in below code with current cursor position at `|`, I'd like to unindent it quickly to the level of `if` statement.

```py
def hello(a):
    if a == 0:
        return
        |            # | is the current cursor position.
```

Comment: does `ctrl u` work?

Comment: Ctrl+u deletes all characters before cursor which means I'll need to re-indent the code in most cases because the expected indent level is not 0.

Comment: Moving around with the arrow keys is so easy, that I only the control keys for big moves.